# Strange behavior of type parameters in "type" versus "newtype": is this a bug or a feature?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm writing a typeclass to add type reflection to Haskell data types. Part of it looks like this:

```
type VarName a = Text


class Reflective a where
   -- | A reflective type may have a fixed name, or it may be a union 
   -- where each variant has a distinct name.
   reflectiveName :: a -> VarName a
   -- | One default value of the type for each reflective name.
   reflectiveDefaults :: [a]
```

The idea is that if I write

```
data ExampleType = Foo Int | Bar String
```

then in the `Reflective` instance `reflectiveName` will return either "Foo" or "Bar" as appropriate, and `reflectiveDefaults` will return `[Foo 0, Bar ""]`

So now I can write a function to give me all the names of the variants:

```
reflectiveNames :: (Reflective a) => [VarName a]
reflectiveNames = map reflectiveName reflectiveDefaults
```

and I can call it like this:

```
exampleNames = reflectiveNames :: [VarName ExampleType]
```

When I compile this I get the following error in the type declaration for `reflectiveNames`:

```
• Could not deduce (Reflective a0)
  from the context: Reflective a
    bound by the type signature for:
               reflectiveNames :: Reflective a => [VarName a]
  The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
```

However if I replace the VarName with a newtype:

```
newtype VarName a = VarName Text
```

then it works.

Is this a feature of the Haskell type system, or is it a bug in GHC? And if the former, why is it inventing a new type variable a0?

Comment: Well `newtype` actually is a `data` with a constructor that takes one parameter. As a result this is a *new* type, wherea `type` is only a type alias. For the type alias the `a` does not matter whether `Reflective` holds, hence the confusion. Whereas for the `newtype`, you can define `instance`s yourself and thus "tag" the `a`s for which it is allowed.

Comment: To make it more clear: say you use `reflectiveNames` with `Text`, then how is Haskell supposed to know what `a` to use? Whereas if you define a `VarName` type, then the `a` has to be passed (and can for a real function application be grounded) to a type, such that it can be checked if the `instance` constraint holds.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I would have expected that if I said `reflectiveNames :: [Text]` then the ambiguity error would have appeared there, rather than in the declaration of `reflectiveNames`.

Comment: well you basically have written, behind the curtains, `reflectiveNames :: Reflective a => [Text]`, since `type` is not a *new* type, but a type alias. And that thus means that Haskell can *not* derive what `a` is for the given type of the function, and this constructs ambiguity. What `reflectiveName` is it supposed to use? That for `a ~ Char`, or `a ~ Int`, or `a ~ ()`, etc.? This might sounds like a detail, but all these instances can have completely different semantics, if the compiler thus had the freedom to simply pick one, then depending on the system, `reflectiveNames` makes sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If you can write this up as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why this fails for a `type`...

If you write `type` then you do *not* construct a new type, you construct an alias. So you defined:

```
type VarName a = Text
```

Hence now each time you write `VarName SomeType`, you have basically written `Text`. So `VarName Char ~ VarName Int ~ Text` (the tilde `~` means that the two types are equal).

Type aliases are useful however since they typically minimize the code (frequently the name of the alias is shorter than its counterpart), it reduces the complexity of signatures (one does not have to remember a large hierarchy of types), and finally it can be used if some types are not yet fully decided (for example time can be modelled as an `Int32`, `Int64`, etc.) and we want to define some placeholder to easily change a large number of signatures.

But the point is that each time you write a `VarName Char` for example, Haskell will replace this with `Text`. So now if we take a look at your function, you have written:

```
reflectiveNames :: Reflective a => [Text]
reflectiveNames = map reflectiveName reflectiveDefaults
```

Now there is a problem with this function: there is a type variable `a` (in `Reflective a`), but nowhere in the signature do we use this type parameter. The problem is that Haskell does not know what `a` to fill in in case you call this function, and that is a real problem (here), since the semantics of `reflectiveName` and `reflectiveDefaults` can be completely different for an `a ~ Char`, then for an `a ~ Int`. The compiler can not just "*pick*" a type for `a`, since that would mean that two different Haskell compilers, could end up with functions that generate different output, and thus a different program (usually one of the fundamental desired aspects of a programming language is *unambiguity*, the fact that there are no two semantically different programs that map on the same source code).

## ... and why it works for a `newtype`

Now why doesn't this happen if we use **`newtype`**? Basically a `newtype` is the same as a `data` declaration, except for some small details: behind the curtains for example, Haskell will *not* produce such constructor, it will simply store the value that is wrapped inside the constructor *but* it will see the value as a different type. The `newtype` definition

```
newtype VarName a = VarName Text
```

is thus (conceptually) almost equivalent to:

```
data VarName a = VarName Text
```

Although Haskell will (given it is a compiler that can deal with such optimization) factor the constructor away, we can conceptually assume that it is there.

But the main difference is that we did *not* define a type signature: we defined a new type, so the function signature stays:

```
reflectiveNames :: Reflective a => [VarName a]
reflectiveNames = map reflectiveName reflectiveDefaults
```

and we can not just write `Text` instead of `VarName a`, since a `Text` is *not* a `VarName a`. It also means that Haskell can perfectly derive what `a` is. If we would for instance trigger `reflectiveNames :: [VarName Char]`, then it know that `a` is a `Char`, and it will thus use the `instance` of `Reflective` for `a ~ Char`. There is no ambiguity. Of course we can define aliasses like:

```
type Foo = VarName Char   -- a ~ Char
type Bar b = VarName Int  -- a ~ Int
```

But then still `a` is resolved to `Char` and `Int` respectively. Since this is a new type, we will always carry the type of `a` through the code, and hence the code is unambiguous.